# How to apply CSS transform if i had a transform on hover?

Tags: javascript, css

I have made a group of elements and set a hover for their class

```
.cards:hover {
    transition: 0.2s;
    transform: translate( 0px, -50px);
    height: 180px;
    width: 120px;
    background-size: 120px 180px;
}
```

There are 10 elements in the class and i have a JS file that onclick singles out the element and i want it to spin so i write the JS and i tell it to add a transform after the click like

```
document.getElementById(idTag).style.transition = "3s ease";
document.getElementById(idTag).style.transform = "rotate(270deg)";
```

but it doesn't rotate it. Instead it goes directly to 270 degrees in the shortest possible path. If i remove the transform from the hover then it rotates like normal but if i have a transform on hover it doesn't work. Is there a conflict or something with the hover effect ?

Comment: Why you don't simply add class to element and leave CSS to CSS?

Comment: rotate a parent element

Comment: I have a container with 10 elements and i want on click only 1 of the elements to do something while the other stay intact. Like drawing 1 card from a spread deck of cards. So i need to do it individualy. Everything works without the :hover transform and i want to know why...

Comment: the why is because you override the transform by setting your transform which is set inline .. that's why you need to deal with classes and CSS

Comment: You override a lot of things why is this a problem ? Dude you are not helping at all, sorry. And i do deal with the classes

Comment: Are you hovering or clicking? Pick one.

Comment: The transition property should be on .cards not on .cards:hover

Answer (score 0):

In order to transition vertical displacement (translate) and rotation separately you should probably use a different way of moving the element upwards. Using the top property and a relative position. Then you could have the following css code...

```
.cards {
    position: relative;
    transition: top 0.2s, transform 3s ease;
    height: 180px;
    width: 120px;
    background-size: 120px 180px;
    top: 0px;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.cards:hover {
    top: -50px;
}

.cards.rotate {
    transform: rotate(270deg);
}
```

And the following code within your click listener to add the rotate class for rotation after the click.

```
document.getElementById(idTag).classList.add('rotate')
```

Now the cards should move up on hover, but rotate on click with separate speeds.

Comment: Thank you for the answer i did it with keyframes.

Comment: Ah ok, maybe post it as an answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
    function drawCard() {
  var Deck = document.getElementsByClassName("cards");
  var idTag = this.id;
  document.getElementById(idTag).classList.remove("cards");
  document.getElementById(idTag).classList.add("draw-card");

  for (i = 0; i < Deck.length; i++) {
    Deck[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  document.getElementById(idTag).style.transition = "2s";
  document.getElementById(idTag).style.left = "100px";
  document.getElementById(idTag).style.animation = "rotate 2s linear forwards";
```

on click I separate the picked card by changing the class and then cycle through the rest of the class to make the rest of the cards dissapear. After that I add the rotate animation with the key frames in CSS

```
    @keyframes rotate {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
  }
```